# Passing ViewController of Type UITextDelegate as parameter

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have a static function in `Util.m`  as

```
+ (UIView *) getBackButtonAsSubViewForNavigationBar:(UIViewController *)targetView :(SEL)targetAction {

       ...
       [button addTarget:targetView action:targetAction ...];

}
```

Inside `MyViewController : UIViewController < UITextFieldDelegate >`, I try to use it as

```
UIView * backBtn = [Util getBackButtonAsSubViewForNavigationBar:self targetAction:@selector(cancelOp)]
```

But Xcode says:

> No Know class for method for selector
>   'getBackButtonAsSubViewForNavigationBar:targetAction:'

What am I missing?

```
Util.h


+ (UIView *) getBackButtonAsSubViewForNavigationBar:(UIViewController *)targetView :(SEL)targetAction;


Util.m

+ (UIView *) getBackButtonAsSubViewForNavigationBar:(UIViewController *)targetView :(SEL)targetAction {

       ...
       [button addTarget:targetView action:targetAction ...];

}
```

cancelOp is as follow:

```
- (IBAction)cancelOp:(id)sender {
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:Nil];
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure if it's the error but you're trying to pass in a view controller for one of the parameters that should be a view.

Comment: Good catch...I changed to UIViewController....did not help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should declare/define method as:

```
Util.h


+ (UIView *) getBackButtonAsSubViewForNavigationBar:(UIViewController *)targetView target:(SEL)targetAction;


Util.m

+ (UIView *) getBackButtonAsSubViewForNavigationBar:(UIViewController *)targetView target:(SEL)targetAction {

       ...
       [button addTarget:targetView action:targetAction ...];

}
```

Comment: it works...thanks...I will read docs again...if you could shed some light as well??

Comment: The error is in parameter definition, you should use xxxxx:(type)name